# Azure App Service Entity Framework: Cannot create new controller: unable to resolve service for type dbcontextoptions

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to create a new controller to have a new table in my db.

Say I take this model:

```
namespace SkillbasedMiddleware.Db
{
    //The fields in this class must match the fields in Models/TodoItem.cs
    public class UserItem : EntityTableData
    {
        [Required, MinLength(1)]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";
        public string Telephone { get; set; } = "";
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

and this context class:

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{

```
public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}

/// <summary>
/// The dataset for the UserItems.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<UserItem> UserItem => Set<UserItem>();

/// <summary>
/// Do any database initialization required.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A task that completes when the database is initialized</returns>
public async Task InitializeDatabaseAsync()
{
    await this.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

}

with my program looking like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("C5"); // set the connection string name that you set up (caused issues before) 

if (connectionString == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("DefaultConnection is not set");
}

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Initialize the database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    await context.InitializeDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Configure and run the web service.
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

This is what I set up:

[image]

And this is what I get after about 20 seconds:

[image]

EDIT:

Appsettingsfile:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TodoApp;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

CSPROJ of the middleware:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>bb5de9dc-de92-4400-8264-ba4598f2142f</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\TodoItemController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Db\TodoItem.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Datasync" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Datasync.EFCore" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` and `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: absolutly. see my edit please @Harshitha

Comment: Are you following any Doc?

Comment: well yeah, I am following those docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/?pivots=vs2022-windows 
following the tutorial actually worked until I wanted to create my own table (the todo items I was able to create and read from the db at azure) but creating my own table always fails when I try to insert data into it (500 internal server error) and when I realized that when I tried to create a controller via the gui that ALSO failed, so I figured that this is the actual issue

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same error when I tried to add the new Controller.

The issue is with the existing `NuGet Packages`.

Open the `Package Manager Console`
`Tools` => `NuGet Package Manager` =>`Package Manager Console`
[image]

- Update the `Entity Framework tools` for latest features.
- First, run the below Command

```cs
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

- Next, run the second command

```cs
dotnet ef migrations add MyDBMigration --project "C:\YourProjectPath\dbcontextoptions.csproj"
```

[image]

- The new folder with name `Migrations` will be created with the
  new table code updated to it.
  [image]

[image]

- In `.csproj` file the below packages are updated to the latest version  `7.0.0`.

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
```

- Now Iam able to craete the new Controller without any issues.
  [image]

Comment: this fails at the second command with: The specified deps.json [D:\Big Projects\skillbased_prod\Skillbased\bin\Debug\net6.0-android\Skillbased.deps.json] does not exis

Comment: The path has to be for `.csproj` file .

Comment: Right click on the Project folder, a file with name `.csproj` will be opened.Copy the path of that file.

Comment: The file will be at the project root folder.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m43s7.png)

Comment: I am running this command: dotnet ef migrations add MyDBMigration --project "D:\Big Projects\skillbased_prod\SkillbasedMiddleware\SkillbasedMiddleware.csproj"